# How to run Jupyter, locally, connecting to Google Cloud VM using only internal IP address?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine, ssh-tunnel

I configured a Compute Engine instance with only an internal IP (10.X.X.10). I am able to ssh into it via gcloud with IAP with tunneling, access and copy files storage via Private Google Access and VPC was set up with no conflicting IP ranges:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone "us-central1-c" "vm_name"  --tunnel-through-iap --project "projectXXX"
```

Now I want to open Jupyter notebook without creating an external IP in the VM.

Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) is working well, Private Google Access also. After that I enabled a NAT Gateway, that generated an external IP (35.X.X.155).

I configured Jupyter by running `jupyter notebook --generate-config`, set up a password `"sha"`

Now I run Jupyter by typing this on gcloud SSH:

```
python /usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8080 --no-browser &
```

Replacing:`http://instance-XXX/?token=abcd`

By:`http://35.X.X.155/?token=abcd`

But the external IP is not accessible, not even in the browser, neither in http nor in https. Note that I'm not considering using a Network Load Balancing, because it's not necessary.

Ping 35.X.X.155 works perfectly

I also tried `jupyter notebook --gateway-url=http://NAT-gateway:8888`
without success

[image: Jupyter Notebook]

Look at this as an alternative to a bastion (VM with external IP)

Any ideas on how to solve this issue ?

UPDATE: Looks like I have to find a way to SSH into the NAT Gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be accomplished [using IAP for TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding), and there is no need to use NAT at all in this scenario. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Ensure you have ports 22 and 8080 allowed in the project's firewall:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
NAME                         NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         DENY  DISABLED
allow-8080-ingress-from-iap  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:8080                            False
allow-ssh-ingress-from-iap   default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:22                              False
```

2. On your endpoint's [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud), log in to GCP and set the project to where the instance is running:

```
gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_NAME
```

3. Check if you already have SSH keys generated in your system:

```
ls -1 ~/.ssh/*

#=>

/. . ./id_rsa
/. . ./id_rsa.pub
```

If you don't have any, you can generate them with the command: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C id_rsa`

4. Add the SSH keys to your project's metadata:

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
--metadata ssh-keys="$(gcloud compute project-info describe \
--format="value(commonInstanceMetadata.items.filter(key:ssh-keys).firstof(value))")
$(whoami):$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"

#=>

Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME].
```

5. Assign the `iap.tunnelResourceAccessor` role to the user:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $GCP_PROJECT_NAME \
    --member=user:$USER_ID \
    --role=roles/iap.tunnelResourceAccessor
```

6. Start an IAP tunnel pointing to your instance:port and bind it to your desired localhost port (in this case, 9000):

```
gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel $INSTANCE_NAME 8080 \
    --local-host-port=localhost:9000

Testing if tunnel connection works.
Listening on port [9000].
```

At this point, you should be able to access your Jupyter Notebook in http://127.0.0.1:9000?token=abcd.

Note: The `start-iap-tunnel` command is not a one-time running command and should be issued and kept running every time you want to access your Jupyter Notebook implementation.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, thanks for the response. I did the steps of your response, `gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel` and is listening. Jupyter is at http://instance:8081 and I used this command: gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel instance 22 --zone=us-central1-a --local-host-port=locahost:8081. Unfortunately, localhost: 8081 is not opening Jupyter yet. When I try to create iap-tunnel on 8080, I have the error 4003 'failed to connect to backend'. The firewall is ok, as you stated.

Comment: Continuing... Jupyter says port 8080 is being used, due to a previous attempt.

Comment: Sure, when I start Jupyter and run `lsof` in other ssh to the same instance, the Jupyter port shows up in lsof listening, but when I put the port on start-iap-tunnel, I still get the error 4003, even with more permissive firewall rule, allowing also the IAP troubleshoot IP, that was set up previously. One thing, I didn't find this role `iap.tunnelResourceAccessor`, only IAP Secured Tunnel User and IAP Secured Web App User..

Comment: I see there is a confusion in the ports, let me try to explain it: The port specified after the instance name is the port where you are exposing the Jupyter Notebook, in the original question is the port 8080, I see you changed it to 8081, if you are now using por 8081 you should create a new firewall rule in your project to allow it; and the localhost port is the one you are binding it to in your local system and the one you will be accessing, in my example port 9000.

Comment: It worked Gabriel. In fact I created another VPC for NAT and Router. Rolling back to Default network, it worked perfectly.