# Why is Cloud Run timing out when the url specifies a port number?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I've deployed a container to Cloud Run that is designed to work only if accessed on a specific port. Localhost access works fine if I access the service by
http://localhost:8080/myendpoint

After deploying to Cloud Run however it times out
https://helloworld-xyzxyzxyz-ew.a.run.app:8080/myendpoint

Is it possible to access services on Cloud Run in this way, with the port specified explicitly in the url?

Comment: Probably you can create a firewall rule with this restriction in the subnet where Cloud Run is located.

Comment: Do you think it is possible then? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress

Comment: I'm not a 'server guy' but I'm thinking that doc above maybe means I can't change the firewall settings. Maybe changing the port to 443 would allow access to my endpoint?

Comment: If you are calling Cloud Run from an instance (Compute Engine), you can connect via internal IP as long as you enable Private Google Access in the subnet where Cloud Run is located (In the same VPC). Then you select `--ingress internal`. However, if your are using an external IP, for instance a personal computer, to connect to an internal IP of Cloud Run, you have to use an IAP tunnel with TCP forwarding, like seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71429262/how-to-run-jupyter-locally-connecting-to-google-cloud-vm-using-only-internal-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public side of Cloud Run **only** supports ports 80 and 443.

Usage of ports like 8080 is for your application to listen to requests from the Google Frontend (GFE). That port number can be configured but the public port numbers that the GFE listens on cannot be changed.

Google Cloud Run and many other services use the GFE (Google Frontend) for load balancing, TLS termination, DDoS protection, and more. The GFE determines which ports are exposed to access the underlying services.

[Google Front End service](https://cloud.google.com/docs/security/infrastructure/design#google_front_end_service)

Two excellent documents about Cloud Run that help to understand the service:

[Cloud Run FAQ](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq)

[Cloud Run container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract)

Comment: thank you. I tried to find this in the documentation. I could be because I don't understand the right terminology but I couldn't see it. If you have a link please let me know. Thank you again :)

Comment: @atreeon - It is not directly documented by Cloud Run but is indirectly by the GFE. I have updated my answer with more information.